# How can I know if a message was deleted with python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using the python-telegram-bot library in a bot that posts a summary of everything uploaded to a channel in a 24h period and it updates itself afterwards with any new content. It's currently being used by about 250 pretty active channels, so I would prefer avoid using the `copy_message` and `forward_message` methods. Is there any built-in or at least simpler way of achieving the same result? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Note that this is not a limitation of `python-telegram-bot`, but of the Bot API. See this [FAQ entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#i-want-to-handle-updates-from-an-external-service-in-addition-to-the-telegram-updates-how-do-i-do-that) of `python-telegram-bot` and also this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api/issues/62) on the repository of the Bot API itself.